# How to Query DateTime with Reactive Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, datetime, reactivemongo

This is what I currently have:

```
BSONDocument("updated" -> BSONDocument("$gte" -> BSONDateTime(DateTime.now.plusDays(-2).getMillis),
            "$lt" -> BSONDateTime(DateTime.now.plusDays(-1).getMillis)))
```

However when I use this I don't get anything back from the db its just stalls, I've been waiting for a response for an hour when it usually takes seconds with other types of queries. 
In the DB shell the dates come up in ISODate format if that helps

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the same query in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it  using
`collection.find(gte("created",BsonDateTime(epoch)))`